# Java integer array with dynamic size

Tags: java

I am trying to use an integer array. Now, there are a couple of things;

> 1. I cannot initialize the size during initialization as it depends on some other condition (can be 1,2,5 elements, etc)
> 2. I want to iterate over it & perform some operation. However, I do know for sure those would be integer elements always

So, my question is how can I initialize the array in this case ?

```
int[] dynamicSizeArr = new int[0];

switch (someVar) {
    case "A":
        dynamicSizeArr = new int[] { 5,10,15,20,25};
        break;
    case "B":
        dynamicSizeArr = new int[] { 10,20};
        break;
    case "C":
        dynamicSizeArr = new int[] { 10};
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dynamicSizeArr.length; i++) {
    x.insert(dynamicSizeArr[i] + i, '.');
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your posted code?

Comment: Personally I would do `int[] dynamicSizeArr  = null;` but the OP code should work

Comment: @ElliottFrisch; I have initialized it with size 0 (new int[0])...I am not sure if that is standard and then I keep on assigning it dynamically like dynamicSizeArr = new int[] { 10,20}, etc

Comment: `ArrayList` is the **standard** way to have a dynamically sized array in Java. By definition, using a primitive array in this way is *unusual*. However, it's not ***wrong***. If your `switch` were in a method that you call, then it wouldn't even be that unusual.

Comment: I would say initializing int[] dynamicSizeArr = {}; would be more natural.

Comment: @testndtv you have written quite good code. It's fine without using Arraylist of java for dynamic sized arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Use java.util.ArrayList in that case.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int n = 5;
//n can be anything
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
       arr.add(i);
```